# Custom Google Map plugin, am I going about this right?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to code a Google Map plugin (well version 2 of my plugin). The code below displays the pins on the map so far, isn't finished but dont want to keep on doing it wrong if I am, it feels, messy.

### Functionality I want it to have?

- Multiple pins.
- Custom info window HTML.
- Ability to put info window content within an element rather than map.
- Toggle map controls on and off.
- Offset the map if using multiple locations or single locations (having issues with this).
- Ability to style map.
- Display layers

Pretty basic functionality really which I can do, having issues with the offset currently, however i'm here just to review my code structure.

I noticed that in order to keep being able to reference my map instance, which was stored before as follows `this.mapReference`, I had to keep on adding either `call()` or `bind()` on new functions, this felt messy.

I have recently moved this map reference to a global variable. Can someone just review the code (maybe remove everything within the functions) and just show the correct way to structure it and execute in the correct order etc?

```
(function() {

  // Define constructor
  this.MarvMap = function() {

    this.errors = {
      map_type: function(e) { return 'MarvMap: You have entered an invalid map type ('+ e +'). Use 1 - 4.' },
      invalid_map_url: 'MarvMap: Unable to load Google Map API, please check the URL.',
      no_container: 'MarvMap: You must reference where to place the map!',
      container_no_exist_id: 'MarvMap: Referenced ID container doesn\'t exist, we can\'t place the map in the future!',
      container_no_exist_elm: 'MarvMap: Referenced Object container doesn\'t exist, we can\'t place the map in the future!',
      invalid_pin_path: function(e) { return 'MarvMap: You have entered an invalid image path for a custom pin: ' + e },
      invalid_animation: function(e) { return 'MarvMap: You have entered an invalid animation index: ' + e },
      invalid_info: function(e) { return 'MarvMap: You have entered an invalid info window index: ' + e }
    }

    // Define option defaults
    var defaults = {
      container: null,
      locations: [
        {
          name: 'Dealer Name 1',
          address: 'Test Address Here',
          lat: 53.019213,
          lng: -2.186890,
          pin: '/img-src/themev2/theme/icon-min.png'
        },
        {
          name: 'Dealer Name 2',
          address: 'Test Address Here',
          lat: 53.020836,
          lng: -2.182940,
          pin: '/img-src/themev2/theme/icon-min.png'
        }
      ],
      offset: [20, 0],
      styles: null,
      type: 1,
      pin: {
        size: [50, 50],
        anchor: 0,
        animation: 0
      },
      zoom: {
        level: 16,
        scroll: false
      },
      info: {
        type: 0,
        html: null,
        maxWidth: 400,
        container: null,
        class: 'map_infowindow'
      },
      ui: {
        zoom: true,
        scale: true,
        all: false
      },
      directions: null,
      api: {
        key: 'key_here',
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={key}&libraries=geometry'
      },
      layers: {
        traffic: false,
        transit: false,
        bike: false
      },
      debug: true
    };
    // Replace key in url with the set key
    defaults.api.url = (defaults.api.url).replace(/\{(.*?)}/, defaults.api.key);

    // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arugments
    if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") this.options = extend(true, defaults, arguments[0]);

    // Initialize the map
    this.init();
  };

  // Public methods
  MarvMap.prototype.init = function() {
    loadApi.call(this);
    ensureApiIsLoaded.call(this);
  };

  var map;

  // Private methods
  function loadApi() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onerror = function(e) {
      exit(this.errors.invalid_api_url);
    };
    script.onload = function () {
      if (this.options.debug) console.log('MarvMap (Debug): Google Map API loaded, using: ' + this.options.api.key);
    }.call(this);
    script.src = this.options.api.url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  function build() {
    let container;
    // Check that the container is set
    if (this.options.container === null) 
      exit(this.errors.no_container);

    container = ObjectOrID(this.options.container);

    var mapProp = {
      mapTypeId: this.map_options.map_type[(this.options.type - 1)],
      scrollwheel: this.options.zoom.scroll,
      disableDefaultUI: this.options.ui.all,
      zoomControl: this.options.ui.zoom,
      scaleControl: this.options.ui.scale,
      zoom: this.options.zoom.level,
      styles: this.options.styles
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(container, mapProp);
    this.mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "", maxWidth: this.options.info.maxWidth});
    this.tile_size = 256;

    // Setup pins
    initPins.call(this);

    // Setup map
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "projection_changed", function() {
      if (this.options.offset !== null) initOffset.call(this);
    }.bind(this));

    // Add additional map layers
    if (this.options.layers.traffic) (new google.maps.TrafficLayer()).setMap(map);
    if (this.options.layers.transit) (new google.maps.TransitLayer()).setMap(map);
    if (this.options.layers.bike) (new google.maps.BicyclingLayer()).setMap(map);
  }

  function initMapOptions() {
    this.map_options = {

      map_type: function(i) {
        if (google.maps.MapTypeId[(i-1)] !== undefined) {
          return google.maps.MapTypeId[(i-1)];
        } else { exit(this.errors.map_type(i)); }
      }.bind(this),

      anchor: function(i) {
        let k = [ 
          [ (this.options.pin.size[0] / 2), this.options.pin.size[1] ], 
          [ (this.options.pin.size[0] / 2), (this.options.pin.size[1] / 2) ] 
        ];
        return k[i];
      }.bind(this),

      animation: function(i) {
        let x = [ google.maps.Animation.DROP, google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE ];
        if (x[i] === undefined)
          exit(this.errors.invalid_animation(i));
        return x[i];
      }.bind(this),

      info: function(i) {
        let x = [
          "<div class='{class}'><h3>{title}</h3><p>{address}</p><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:{lat}+{lng}' target='_blank'>Go to Maps</a></div>",
          "<div class='{class}'><h3>{title}</h3><p>{address}</p><a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:{lat}+{lng}' target='_blank'>Go to Maps</a><iframe src='https://maps.google.com/maps?q={lat},{lng}&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed' width='100%' height='200px'></iframe></div>"
        ];
        if (x[i] === undefined)
          exit(this.errors.invalid_info(i));
        return x[i];
      }.bind(this)

    };
  }
  function initOffset() {
    let x = this.mapBounds.getCenter().lat();
    let y = this.mapBounds.getCenter().lng();
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);

    var worldCoordinate = project(this, latlng);

    var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
      Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x * this.options.zoom.level) + this.options.offset[0]),
      Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y * this.options.zoom.level)  + this.options.offset[0]));

    var newLatLng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(pixelCoordinate.x, pixelCoordinate.y));
    console.log('0 - Lat: ' + latlng.lat() + ' Lng: ' + latlng.lng());
    console.log('1 - Lat: ' + newLatLng.lat() + ' Lng: ' + newLatLng.lng());
    map.setCenter(newLatLng);

  };

  function project(global, latLng) {
    var siny = Math.sin(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180);
    siny = Math.min(Math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);
    return new google.maps.Point(
      global.tile_size * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
      global.tile_size * (0.5 - Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * Math.PI)));
  }

  function initPins(location, num) {
    this.pins = [];

    var createPin = function(locations, x) {

      // Check image exists
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.onerror = function() { exit(this.errors.invalid_pin_path(locations[x].pin)); }.bind(this);
      img.onload = function() { 
        img.remove(); 
        if (this.options.debug) console.log('MarvMap (Debug): Map pin (' + locations[x].pin + ') exists on server.'); 
      }.bind(this);
      img.src = locations[x].pin;
      img.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(img);

      let anchor = this.map_options.anchor(this.options.pin.anchor);

      // Create pin object
      let image = {
        url: locations[x].pin,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(this.options.pin.size[0], this.options.pin.size[1]),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(anchor[0], anchor[1] )
      };

      // Create pin object
      this.pins[x] = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: image, 
        map: map, 
        position: {lat: this.options.locations[x].lat, lng: this.options.locations[x].lng},
        title: this.options.locations[x].name,
        animation: this.map_options.animation(this.options.pin.animation),
        address: this.options.locations[x].address
      });

      // Add event listeners for pin click events
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.pins[x], 'click', function() {
        // Get pre-set HTML or custom HTML
        let html = (this.options.info.html !== null) ? this.options.info.html : this.map_options.info(this.options.info.type);

        // Replace bracelets in HTML
        html = html.replace(/\{(title)}/g, this.options.locations[x].name);
        html = html.replace(/\{(address)}/g, this.options.locations[x].address);
        html = html.replace(/\{(lat)}/g, this.options.locations[x].lat);
        html = html.replace(/\{(lng)}/g, this.options.locations[x].lng);
        html = html.replace(/\{(class)}/g, this.options.info.class);

        if (this.options.info.container !== null) {
          ObjectOrID(this.options.info.container).innerHTML = html; 
          return;
        }

        (this.infoWindow).setContent(html);
        (this.infoWindow).open(map, this.pins[x]);

      }.bind(this));

    }.bind(this);

    for(var x = 0; x < Object.keys(this.options.locations).length; x++) {
      (this.pins).push(createPin(this.options.locations, x));
      (this.mapBounds).extend(new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.locations[x].lat, this.options.locations[x].lng));
    }
    map.fitBounds(this.mapBounds);
    map.setZoom(this.options.zoom.level);

    /*
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: this.mapBounds
    });
    */
  }

  // Helpers
  function ObjectOrID(x) {
    if (typeof x === "string") {
      let elm = document.getElementById(x);
      if (elm) 
        return elm; if (this.options.debug) console.log('MarvMap (Debug): Reference to element ID passed.');
      exit(this.errors.container_no_exist_id);
    } else {
      if (x) 
        return x; if (this.options.debug) console.log('MarvMap (Debug): Reference to element object passed.');
      exit(this.errors.container_no_exist_elm);
    }
  }
  function exit(message = 'Exiting MarvMap') { throw new Error(message); }
  function ensureApiIsLoaded(){
    if(typeof google == 'undefined'){
      setTimeout(ensureApiIsLoaded.bind(this), 125);
      return;
    } else {
      initMapOptions.call(this); // Setup map options and map reference
      build.call(this); // Build the map
    }
  };
  var extend = function () {

    // Variables
    var extended = {};
    var deep = false;
    var i = 0;
    var length = arguments.length;

    // Check if a deep merge
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Boolean]' ) {
      deep = arguments[0];
      i++;
    }

    // Merge the object into the extended object
    var merge = function (obj) {
      for ( var prop in obj ) {
        if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
          // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
          if ( deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ) {
            extended[prop] = extend( true, extended[prop], obj[prop] );
          } else {
            extended[prop] = obj[prop];
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
      var obj = arguments[i];
      merge(obj);
    }

    return extended;

  };
  Element.prototype.remove = function() { this.parentElement.removeChild(this); }

}());
```